# How to enable IDN support in PHP (cURL)?

Tags: php, curl, wamp, idn

My cURL configuration (fro `phpinfo()` function) is:

```
    cURL support    enabled
    cURL Information    7.21.7
    Age 3
    Features
    AsynchDNS   Yes
    Debug   No
    GSS-Negotiate   Yes
    IDN No
    IPv6    Yes
    Largefile   Yes
    NTLM    Yes
    SPNEGO  No
    SSL Yes
    SSPI    Yes
    krb4    No
    libz    Yes
    CharConv    No
    Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
    Host    i386-pc-win32
    SSL Version OpenSSL/0.9.8r
    ZLib Version    1.2.5
    libSSH Version  libssh2/1.2.7
```

IDN has as value **No**. Can I enable it? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem with the library http://phlymail.com/en/downloads/idna/

Answer (score 2):

You will have to download libcURL 7.21.7 (or some other binary compatible version) and recompile it with IDN support. You will need [libidn](http://www.gnu.org/software/libidn/) installed in your system (including development files in the machine where you'll build libcURL).

Alternatively, you can also download the most recent version of libcURL, but you will likely have to recompile PHP (or at least the cURL extension) in that case.

Note that you can also preprocess your URLs using [`idn_to_ascii`](http://php.net/idn_to_ascii).